# Python, SQlite3 - Querying condition equals and not in (Multiple)

Tags: python, sqlite

How can I query in python both for where a condition equals a value i.e. r.user = (given user id) and where a value is NOT IN (given list of movie ids) the result set.

This is what I currently have

```
placeholder = '?'  # For SQLite. See DBAPI paramstyle.
placeholders = ', '.join(placeholder * len(l))

query = 'SELECT r.user, r.movie, r.rating, m.title FROM ratings r JOIN movies m ON (r.movie = m.id) ' \
'WHERE r.user = 405 AND r.rating >= 3 AND r.movie NOT IN (%s)' % placeholders

cursor.execute(query, ('405', l))
movies_table = cursor.fetchall()
```

l refers to an array of values i.e. so I can get the result set where movie id is not in the list of values.

Thanks very much,

I'm currently able to get one or the other but not both due to what seems the number of parameters applied or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `cursor.execute()` with *one* item per-placeholder.

Try something like this:

```
cursor.execute(query, tuple(l))
```

If you want to append the `405` to the list of values, then you can do something like:

```
cursor.execute(query, (405, *l))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! 

Do you mean as in having another placeholder i.e. after user so I can have a condition of where user = {n} and r.movie not in {list}

`WHERE r.user = (%s)' % user + ' AND r.rating >= 3 AND r.movie NOT IN (%s)' % placeholders 
`

Thanks!

Comment: You need to make sure that the tuple you are passing to `execute` has the same number of values as there are placeholders (and are in the right order).  If you want to use a placeholder for `user` and `movie`, then you can try using `(405, *l)`.

Comment: Thanks again, made me search further. I'm currently using Python 2.7 and managed to find out and I see from as you said about passing the same number of values to placeholder in the correct order. I was able to insert the user id at the beginning of the l list which now works fine. Seems that that's how it works in that it depends on the same number of values and in the correct order.

Comment: `placeholder = '?'  # For SQLite. See DBAPI paramstyle.
placeholders = ', '.join(placeholder * len(l))

query = 'SELECT r.user, r.movie, r.rating, m.title FROM ratings r JOIN movies m ON (r.movie = m.id) ' \
'WHERE r.user = ? AND r.rating >= 3 AND r.movie NOT IN (%s)' % placeholders

l.insert(0, user)
cursor.execute(query, (l))`